# Код работает только если переоткрывать файл

Tags: kernel, c, linux

Намучался. Почему этот код не работает:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[], const char *envp[])
{
    long double a[4], b[4], loadavg;
    FILE *pstat_fp;

    pstat_fp = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
    if (pstat_fp == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to open file \"myfile\"");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (;;) {
        fscanf(pstat_fp, "cpu  %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3]);
        rewind(pstat_fp);
        sleep(1);
        fscanf(pstat_fp, "cpu  %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf", &b[0], &b[1], &b[2], &b[3]);
        rewind(pstat_fp);

        loadavg = ((b[0]+b[1]+b[2]) - (a[0]+a[1]+a[2])) / ((b[0]+b[1]+b[2]+b[3]) - (a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[3]));
        loadavg *= 100;

        // OUTPUT
        printf("CPU: %2.Lf%%\n", loadavg);
    }

    fclose(pstat_fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Но этот код работает:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[], const char *envp[])
{
    long double a[4], b[4], loadavg;
    FILE *pstat_fp;

    for (;;) {
        pstat_fp = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
        if (pstat_fp == NULL) {
            perror("Failed to open file \"myfile\"");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        fscanf(pstat_fp, "cpu  %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3]);
        rewind(pstat_fp);
        sleep(1);
        fscanf(pstat_fp, "cpu  %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf", &b[0], &b[1], &b[2], &b[3]);
        fclose(pstat_fp);

        loadavg = ((b[0]+b[1]+b[2]) - (a[0]+a[1]+a[2])) / ((b[0]+b[1]+b[2]+b[3]) - (a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[3]));
        loadavg *= 100;

        printf("CPU: %2.Lf%%\n", loadavg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Принтами содержимое файла выводится, но проблема с fscanf, при чтении b[3] программа падает.
Пробовал уже и странное:

```
fread(buf, 199, 1, pstat_fp);
sscanf(buf, "cpu  %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf", &b[0], &b[1], &b[2], &b[3]);
```

Comment: for (;;) бесконечный цикл?

Comment: > for (;;) бесконечный цикл?

Да.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шутка юмора оказалась в `setbuf(pstat_fp, NULL)` :) Так что получается вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[], const char *envp[])
{
    long double a[4], b[4], cpuLoad;
    FILE *pstat_fp;

    if (!(pstat_fp = fopen("/proc/stat", "r"))) {
        perror("Failed to open file \"myfile\"");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (;;) {
        fscanf(pstat_fp, "cpu  %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3]);
        rewind(pstat_fp);
        setbuf(pstat_fp, NULL);

        sleep(1);

        fscanf(pstat_fp, "cpu  %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf", &b[0], &b[1], &b[2], &b[3]);
        rewind(pstat_fp);
        setbuf(pstat_fp, NULL);

        cpuLoad= ((b[0]+b[1]+b[2]) - (a[0]+a[1]+a[2])) / ((b[0]+b[1]+b[2]+b[3]) - (a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[3]));
        cpuLoad *= 100;

        printf("CPU: %2.Lf%%\n", cpuLoad);
    }

    fclose(pstat_fp);
    return 0;
}
```